# Browser Cache Headers Change on Server (Spring MVC + tomcat)

Tags: java, spring, browser-cache, cache-control

My spring MVC app works well on localhost. I have the following bean that set browser caches:

```
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    // @formatter:off
    registry.addResourceHandler("/doc/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/doc/").setCacheControl(DEFAULT_BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/style/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/style/").setCacheControl(DEFAULT_BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/image/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/image/").setCacheControl(DEFAULT_BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/javascript/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/javascript/").setCacheControl(DEFAULT_BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/plugin/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/plugin/").setCacheControl(DEFAULT_BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/root/").setCacheControl(DEFAULT_BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL);
    // @formatter:on
};
```

Very surprisingly, when I deploy my app to a server and publish on tomcat, the browser caches do not work. For the exacy same image, the response headers are as below

server: cache-control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

localhost: Cache-Control:max-age=86400, public

how is this possible ? I do not have any special configuration on tomcat.

Comment: I think what you are doing is setting to DEFAULT_BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL and what I am seeing here is that there might be difference in your local and server tomcat instance or probably the operating system might also come into picture for creating difference.

Comment: DEFAULT_BROWSER_CACHE_CONTROL is an integer variable within the same class. Before it was a number, I moved the number into a variable. Hence there is no chance that it explains the situation.